# Classloader leak because of invalid SSL certificate in SolrJ, HttpClient, JVM or my application?

Tags: java, ssl, solr, memory-leaks, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've analyzed a classloader leak the last few days in a large application and I've worked out the problem.

My application uses SolrJ which will be initialilzed through a `@Bean`-Method:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public SolrClient solrClient() {
    return new HttpSolrClient(SOLR_URL);
}
```

SolrJ (`org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:5.4.1`) uses the Apache HttpClient (`org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1`). The HttpClient initializes the SSL context by using normal java classes like `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`.
In this way java loads the trustManager and analyzes all trusted certificates. If there is an error the certificate (an instance of `sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl`) is stored in a list and gets enriched by the thrown exception.
This exception is swallowed and my application remains unaware.

As far as I can see, the SSL Context is in the System / Root Classloader, my Application is in the dedicated `WebappClassLoader` and this is the problem because now there is an `IOException` inside of the SSL context which contains references in the stacktrace, backtrace and so on to classes in my application.

But now I don't know where this came from. Is it the SolrJ client, the Apache HttpClient, Java itself (the JVM) or is it my application?

I have made a small application to reproduce the problem which you can find here: https://github.com/CptS/solrj-classloader-leak
This also contains a Workaround (a shutdown hook which removes the references which leads to the classloader leak).

If you disable the shutdown hook (e.g. by commenting it out) and start a clean Tomcat (see "Environment to reproduce" below) you can reproduce it by following this steps:

1. deploy the war of the demo project (A)
2. reload it (B)
3. reload it again (C)
4. Trigger GC (D)
5. undeploy
6. Trigger GC (E)
7. See that the metaspace gets not completly cleaned up (F)

[image]

I've create a heap dump and the *shortest path to GC* looks like this:

[image]

This was the same as in my large application.
The mentioned Workaround (a little bit inspired by https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention, but this unfortunately doesn't solve my problem) searches by using reflection for these `unparseableExtensions` and removes the Exception stored in the `why` field through this way: 
`SSLContextImpl.DefaultSSLContext#defaultImpl` -> `SSLContextImpl#trustManager` -> `X509TrustManager#trustedCerts` -> `X509CertImpl#info` -> `X509CertInfo#extensions` -> `CertificateExtensions#unparseableExtensions` -> `UnparseableExtension#why`

By doing this i've got the stacktrace of the exception if it helps someone:

```
java.io.IOException: No data available in passed DER encoded value.
    at sun.security.x509.GeneralNames.<init>(GeneralNames.java:61)
    at sun.security.x509.IssuerAlternativeNameExtension.<init>(IssuerAlternativeNameExtension.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateExtensions.parseExtension(CertificateExtensions.java:113)
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateExtensions.init(CertificateExtensions.java:88)
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateExtensions.<init>(CertificateExtensions.java:78)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:702)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:167)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1804)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:195)
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:100)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:755)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getCacertsKeyStore(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.getDefaultTrustManager(SSLContextImpl.java:767)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:733)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1595)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:96)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getSystemSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.java:190)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createSystemDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(SystemDefaultHttpClient.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:484)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.setMaxConnections(HttpClientUtil.java:234)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientConfigurer.configure(HttpClientConfigurer.java:40)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.configureClient(HttpClientUtil.java:149)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.createClient(HttpClientUtil.java:125)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.<init>(HttpSolrClient.java:189)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.<init>(HttpSolrClient.java:162)
    at de.test.spring.SolrJConfig.solrClient(SolrJConfig.java:20)
    at de.test.spring.SolrJConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dbd4362f.CGLIB$solrClient$0(<generated>)
    at de.test.spring.SolrJConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dbd4362f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8e7566a6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at de.test.spring.SolrJConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dbd4362f.solrClient(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at de.test.WicketApplication.init(WicketApplication.java:32)
    at org.apache.wicket.Application.initApplication(Application.java:950)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:429)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4640)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5247)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1703)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My workaround solves the problem for now, but of course this is just a workaround.

I want to know and maybe someone can answer one or more of my question:

1. Is this a *"bug"* in SolrJ, HttpClient, Java or my application?
2. If it is my application, what I am doing wrong?
3. If it is not my application, is it a known problem? I can't find any information about this. (Where) should I create a bug ticket?
4. Why is there a *"invalid"* certificate? (BTW: Maybe the leak would also be solve if I remove this certificate from the trust store... I haven't tested but I think a invalid or damaged certificate should never lead to a classloader leak...)
5. Has anyone some more information on this? I can't belive that I'm the only one who detect this behaviour (except it is my appication... see my question 2).

At last but not least, my Environment to reproduce:

- Tomcat Version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.14 (Debian)
- JVM Version: 1.8.0_91-b14
- JVM Vendor: Oracle Corporation
- OS Name: Linux
- OS Version: 3.16.0-4-amd64
- Architecture: amd64

Comment: For those who want to reproduce the issue: I have added some information about the solr server and the Keystore to the `README.md` on GitHub: https://github.com/CptS/solrj-classloader-leak#environment

Comment: UPDATE: It seems Mattias Jiderhamn shares my opinion that it's a java bug: https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention/issues/58#issuecomment-252438440

Comment: Does not sound like a bug of JDK at a first look. Need more information for further evaluation. Is the GC behavior reproducible if the cert in keystore is valid? For performance, the SSLContext may cache some trusted certificates in static fields. The memory use may increase for the first time use of SSLContext. What's the behavior if deploy/undeploy multiple times? For example, perform 1-7/A-F for 10 times.

Comment: I'm not completely sure which information you want, but you can simply try it yourself with the demo project: https://github.com/CptS/solrj-classloader-leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in java, the bug ticket is here: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8168069

Many thanks to [mjiderhamn (on GitHub)](https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention/issues/58#issuecomment-255593567). He is the developer of the great [classloader-leak-prevention](https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention/) library and has now included a preventor for this issue (version 2.1.0).

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there a "invalid" certificate

The "Issuer Alternative Name" extension value of the cert in the key store is empty, which does not follow the X.509 specification.  See section 4.2.1.6 and 4.2.1.7 of RFC 5280.

```
$ keytool -exportcert ... -file ... 
$ keytool -printcert -v -file ...
...
#10: ObjectId: 2.5.29.18 Criticality=false 
Unparseable IssuerAlternativeName extension due to 
java.io.IOException: No data available in passed DER encoded value.

0000: 30 00                                              0.
```

Comment: Yes, I understand this. Sry, my question has been phrased incorrectly. It's a fresh installed and clean debian with a fresh installed oracle jvm and a (also fresh installed) tomcat. I havn't installed any certificates by myself. So the invalid certificate comes from a distributed package. This surprised me, and this is what I meant with this question.